# datatables custom filter not search

Tags: jquery, datatables

I currently have custom filter buttons that use the search API function of the database.

HTML

```
  <ul>
                    <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-type="all">All</a></li>
                    <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-type="video">Video</a></li>
                    <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-type="image">Image</a></li>
                    <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-type="upload">Upload Dash</a></li>
                    <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-type="link">Code Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
```

JQuery

```
 var table = $('#rlist').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'T <'clearfix'>f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax": baseurl+"media/ajax_fetch"       

    });

    $('ul').on('click', 'a', function() {

          table
            .columns(1)
            .search($(this).text())
            .draw();
        });

        $('ul').on('click', 'a.all', function() {

          table
            .search('')
            .columns(1)
            .search('')
            .draw();
        });
```

The problem is I don't want to use the search API, I want to send the button  `data-type` attribute to the server side where I can manipulate manually not interfering with the search function.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a similar functionality with my current project. Basically, you need to modify your click events to take the element's `data-type` attribute, call an ajax with that data, then clear the table and add the new searched data.

You will need to clear the client side table everytime you search doing it through this approach though.

```js
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var elementType = $(this).attr("data-type");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //assuming server url is something like '/someURL/{elementType}'
    url: urlToServer + elementType, 
    success: function(response) {
      if (response) {
        table.clear().rows.add(response).draw();
      }
      //no data back from server
      else table.clear();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have pagination set up, does this update pagination?  For example if the filter has 20 total results but i'm only showing 10 per page?  Will datatables update pagination?

Comment: If you use `.clear()` as I suggest, any settings you set during datatables initialization will be retained. This includes things like rendering functions, pagination settings, sorting settings, etc.